# Physical mechanisms of Joule-Thomson effect

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, gas

I've been trying to wrap my mind around the physical mechanism behind the Joule-Thomson effect for a few years and I think I finally understand it, but I need some external wise minds to chime in and let me know if I'm off-base.

By the way, I really like the explanations given here https://youtu.be/cvjoGjl_7j0 and here https://youtu.be/b9sxqoifksQ and the response by user stuffu here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/616532

My reasoning is that the decrease in temperature during *some* isenthalpic processes of real gases is due to the initial intermolecular spacing and if it's either to the left or right of the sweet spot. If it's initially to the left of that spot and above the x-axis and pressure decreases, then the drop in intermolecular potential energy due to Coulomb repulsion (and an associated increase in intermolecular spacing) results in higher collective kinetic energy, which is really just an increase in internal energy with an associated rise in temperature. Conversely, if we start at the sweet spot or anywhere to the right of it, decreases in pressure result in further distancing and an increase in the potential energy at the expense of internal energy and we observe a decrease in temperature. Given the shallow nature of the curve to the right of the sweet spot, the decrease in temperature is modest and approaches some asymptotic value as vacuum is approached. In the lower left corner, either temperature effect is possible, depending on the final intermolecular separation relative to the initial (decrease in PE -> higher final T, increase in PE -> lower final T).

If enthalpy is too high, then the molecules are already highly energetic and packed together too tightly and the final PE cannot ever be higher than the initial PE, so an increase in T is always observed after throttling at this high enthalpy.

In my mind, I'm still having trouble getting it all to fit the behavior observed along the isenthalps of the P-T diagram typically used in the textbook derivations of the JT coefficient and inversion line. Please let me know if you see any fatal flaws in the reasoning I've shared.

(first diagram by me, second diagram taken from https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Engineering_thermodynamics/Joule-Thomson_effect

[image: JT Effect as a result of by IMFs]

[image]

Comment: What role do you think viscous heating plays in the JT effect?

Comment: It seems like the viscous dissipation of momentum from coherent Pv flow pressure energy into incoherent internal energy would always serve to increase temperature (or perhaps vapor generation in the case of saturated conditions).

Comment: That is correct.  That is why a gas does not cool when its pressure decreases in flow through a porous plug and why a liquid heats when experiencing a large pressure decrease in flow through a porous plug or tube.  So viscous dissipation has a very significant mechanistic impact on JT effect.

Comment: But JT can go either way, increasing or decreasing temperature depending on the initial state and the amount by which pressure drops isenthalpically.  Some (indeed most normal) gases do decrease in temperature when passed through a porous plug when their temperature is within "normal" limits. Not saying viscous dissipation doesn't have its influence, but in certain cases (i.e. when the plug's exit state occurs to the left of the inversion curve and the initial state was not at too low of a temperature) the opposite effect to what you described is observed.

Comment: Yes.  In some cases, expansion cooling wins out, and in some cases, viscous heating wins out.  For a liquid, viscous heating always wins out.